# Why are spaces not allowed in some bash commands, like 'alias'?

Tags: bash

I know that the alias command in bash will not work if there are spaces next to the equals sign. For example,

```
alias loadcode='vim *.c *.h Makefile'
```

works, but

```
alias loadcode ='vim *.c *.h Makefile'
```

or

```
alias loadcode= 'vim *.c *.h Makefile'
```

or

```
alias loadcode = 'vim *.c *.h Makefile'
```

do not work. Why is this?

Comment: Ask Ken Thompson and John Mashey!

Comment: Spaces are allowed, just not around the equals sign. That’s the shell syntax. Asking “why” leads this into opinion territory, in my ... opinion :)

Comment: @JeffSchaller There are over 24,000 questions on this stack exchange, about 1 in 5, that ask "why" something is the case. There are about 30 questions with over 100 votes that ask "why" something is the case.

Comment: asking why a script doesn’t work or behaves differently than expected is something that can be explained by bringing the script or the OP into agreement.  There is no misunderstanding here that (I think) can be answered.

Comment: "Why" questions ... Feynman's take on them: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMFPe-DwULM

Comment: The problem isn't that you're asking  "why", it's that you're asking "why did the developers of this language choose this specific syntax" and that is something only the developers can answer.

Comment: @terdon As the two answers to this question have already shown, there are objective answers to this question.

Comment: I don't see how either answer is giving any objective reason. They're basically saying "because that's how the `=` works everywhere in the shell" which simply moves the question back to "why are no spaces allowed around `=` in shells". Wherever `=` is used as an assignment (an not an equality) operator, spaces break it. The why of it was a question of design choice.

Comment: @terdon No! They gave very specific information that I did not know: that the alias command accepts MULTIPLE aliases SEPARATED BY SPACES which is the reason. If multiple aliases had been separated by some other character then having spaces would be ok.

Comment: Not really. At least I don't think so (which, by the way, demonstrates how this is opinion based ;) ) since every single use of `=` to assign something to something else in the shell works this way. This is not specific to alias, it happens wherever `=` is used to set a value. In any case, if you feel your question has been answered, then all's well that ends well, right?

Comment: @terdon Yes, it has been answered, but I see no reason why not to allow other answers which might add more information and be even better.

Comment: Please open a discussion on meta then. I'm sorry, but I don't see how this can be anything but opinion based and at least two users have agreed. If you disagree, this should be taken to meta where all such discussions belong.

Answer (score 4):

Because `alias` can be used to query aliases, and to set multiple aliases at one time:

```
$ alias foo                       # query for one alias
bash: alias: foo: not found

$ alias foo = bar                 # query for three aliaes
bash: alias: foo: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: bar: not found

$ alias foo=bar doo=dar           # set two aliases
$ alias doo                       # query one alias
alias doo='dar'

$ alias foo = bar                 # query three, again
alias foo='bar'
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: bar: not found
```

(Don't ask me why it says that the alias `=` is not found, instead of telling it's an invalid name for an alias. Which I think it is, I can't find a way to set an alias of that name.)

Of course, having it that way is also in line with how whitespace works in shell variable assignment:

```
$ foo=bar doo=dar
$ echo "$doo"
dar
```

Comment: Funnily, in `zsh` you have the reverse problem. `zsh` complains on `alias =` even though it is possible to define an alias for `=` (with `aliases[=]=something`)

Answer (score 1):

Spaces **are** allowed, performing their usual bash duty of separating command line arguments.

Specifically in respect of `alias`....

Give `alias` an argument without `=` in it and alias will try and print an existing alias of that name.

But give `alias` an argument with `=` in it, then it creates the new alias.

You can combine printing and definition on one line if you feel the urge.