# Attempting to add any alias to .bashrc file is always failing

Tags: bash, alias

My attempts to add any alias to .bashrc file is always failing. It comes as not found.

Let me explain what I tried.

I opened the .bashrc using the subl and then at last added the words

```
alias rm = "rm -i"
```

Then I went to terminal and ran the .bashrc file using

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Closed and then reopened the terminal.

On opening I get an error message

```
bash: alias: rm: not found
bash: alias: = rm -i: not found
```

Comment: Helpful, but maybe not a duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function

Comment: @Jeff Schaller thanks for the link. I saw through the link. The case usage of alias by me is justified as outlined in the post. Still I am getting an error.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/410651/117549 (I'd consider this to be a duplicate of that)

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: This lesson applies to the shell "in general" -- shell syntax is extremely picky about where you put your whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spaces surrounding the equal sign

```
alias rm="rm -i"
```